# Crontab won't restart Docker container

Tags: docker, ubuntu, cron, ubuntu-16.04, docker-container

I have a container that runs under a Root account which I can start using:

```
docker start containername
```

and I want crontab to start it, so as root I used

```
crontab -e
```

and set an entry like this:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/docker start containername
```

but it won't work. I also tried

```
* * * * * root /usr/bin/docker start containername
```

with no luck.

Anyone has a clue on how I can make this work?

Comment: Do you get any errors? Did you check the logs?

Comment: Does the container exist? 
check `docker ps -a` as root. If it is not listed then `docker start` will not work. You may need to run the container using `docker run`. But as @Bmitch said, we need logs or errors otherwise we are guessing

Comment: docker start is used for starting a exited container, what does the container actually execute?

Answer (score 5):

I did it without any problems as follows:

```
$ crontab -e
```

then I set a restart for a container every 5 minutes:

```
*/5 * * * * docker restart <containername>
```

Answer (score 0):

Restarting docker requires sudo privileges.I use the following method:
sudo crontab -e
00 23  * * * docker restart dbprod

Comment: I could be wrong. But, it should not require sudo. I believe you might just need to see this link: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/#manage-docker-as-a-non-root-user

Answer (score 0):

There are two options.

```
docker container restart CONTAINER_NAME

docker restart CONTAINER_NAME
```

1. `sudo crontab -e`
2. `0 1 * * * docker container restart CONTAINER_NAME`

You can see with the next command:

```
sudo crontab -l
```

Test with Docker version 19.03.6, build 369ce74a3c

Comment: Is there any reason you used sudo for crontab? If your user doesn't require sudo to access docker commands, then you shouldn't need sudo on crontab. 

Here is a link to make sure your user doesn't need sudo to access docker commands: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/#manage-docker-as-a-non-root-user

Comment: The example included sudo because there are cases where it is necessary, but if you don't require it you can't use it, sudo is only used to execute processes with administrator privileges.

Comment: As a "linux best practice", you should default to not using sudo. Restarting a docker container is definitely a case when sudo should be absolutely unnecessary.